# MySQL 5.5 but PHP only has MySQL 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i've installed MySQL 5.5 on my Debian squeeze.
I'm using PHP 5.3.x.
When i login into phpmyadmin it says that my client version is different from the server version which can cause unknown behavior.
So how can i tell php to use mysql 5.5?

Comment: Check which MySQL driver version you have installed for PHP, should be in your Apache config somewhere.

Comment: didn't found anything in my apache.conf or my php.ini